# After i pip install external libraries i can not use them

Tags: python

I just want to say in advance that im very new to python and coding in general.
I am trying to let the results of my code be displayed as a graph, but after i installed matplotlib in my console i could not import it into my Python code.
I am using PyCharm for writing my code an that was not the first time something like that happened to me.
The error message i am getting is "No module named 'matplotlib'".
I only wrote one line so far and that line was copied from a tutorial.
What do i have to do, to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you creating environments ? Also, are you on Linux, there is difference between `pip` and `pip3`.

Comment: It's likely that PyCharm created a virtual environment for your project (I believe it will do this by default), meaning that your code will not be using the packages you installed system-wide. If you go to File > Settings > Project Interpreter you can use the + button there to install packages into your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

make virtual environment and then go to `File>Setting>Project>Python Interperter` and add matplotlib and press Apply and then Ok

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PyCharm console, that help me sometime.
Just open a PyCharm Project console and write "pip install matplotlib"

Answer (score 0):

Go to File> Settings> Project :your_project_name > Project Interpreter
Now click the “Green plus sign” in the upper right corner.
Type the name of the module you want to download
Click  “install package”.

Or

when you are typing your code, type the symbol(in this case matplotlib) and then hit Alt+Enter. The module must install immediately adding the import line at start of code.